# Rails - Root Path seems to be ignored when render is involved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, routes, document-root

I have a controller#new which I use as root path.

Routes.rb

```
  resources :participants

  root :to => 'participants#new'
```

Rake routes

```
    participants GET    /participants(.:format)          participants#index
                 POST   /participants(.:format)          participants#create
 new_participant GET    /participants/new(.:format)      participants#new
edit_participant GET    /participants/:id/edit(.:format) participants#edit
     participant GET    /participants/:id(.:format)      participants#show
                 PUT    /participants/:id(.:format)      participants#update
                 DELETE /participants/:id(.:format)      participants#destroy
            root        /                                participants#new
```

And this works great when just visiting xxx.xx/

But when I render #new in the controller i get redirected to /participants , how can I stop this from happening?

```
  def create

    @participant = Participant.new(params[:participant])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @participant.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "<h2>Tack!</h2> <p>Registrering genomförd, vi har skickat ut ett mail med instruktioner till #{@participant.email}</p>".html_safe }
        format.json { render json: @participant, status: :created, location: @participant }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @participant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

LOG:

```
Started POST "/participants" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-13 13:21:29 +0100
Processing by ParticipantsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dXmuTX/ugwgNjc21PPdiSHDGlNXEEGZCRHVIWKELOuw=", "participant"=>{"company"=>"asd", "f_name"=>"asd", "l_name"=>"asd", "email"=>"asd@asd.com", "phone_number"=>"asd", "allergy"=>"asd"}, "commit"=>"Anmäl mig!"}
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=damn_development command={:count=>"models", :query=>{"company"=>"asd", "_type"=>{"$in"=>["Participant"]}}} (0.7780ms)
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=damn_development collection=models selector={"email"=>"asd@asd.com", "_type"=>{"$in"=>["Participant"]}} flags=[] limit=1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields={:_id=>1} (0.5569ms)
  Rendered participants/_form.html.erb (4.7ms)
  Rendered participants/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 19.8ms)
```

Comment: did you try just `render 'new'`?

Comment: show your log that created when you do render new.

Comment: @Zippie - Yeah. Did not help.

Comment: @SaurabhJain - Updated my q with log! thanks!

Comment: It is rendering new by your logs. See `Rendered participants/new.html.erb`

Comment: Yeah but how do I fix this?

Comment: Can you post the `new` action?

Comment: Did your participants got saved in db?

Comment: No this is only when the user can't be saved because validation error.

Comment: well if your participants are not saving into the db than you will go to else part of your create action and it will render new and that is what you are getting.

Comment: But isn't the OP issue that `/participants` aka the `index` is being called instead of the `new` view template?

Comment: no, its that `new` is being called as you see in the log too- `Rendered participants/new.html.erb`

Comment: But I am confused because the OP said before that due to validation error, the data is not saved and I am rendering new but its not rendering.

Comment: When validation fails I want the page to render / as #participants#new but now it renders /participants as #participants#new

Comment: this is because `render /` is equivalent to `render root_path` which is your `participants/new` as defined in routes.rb. So it is rendering `/participants` as `#participants#new`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get sent to `/participants` is because that's the route for the create action.  You can't do anything about it unless you change your routes and your form.  In your route, you can match the create action to '/' but only via `post`.  Then in your form, use '/' as the action.

Comment: Thanks, from what I've understood from your answer is that I can't use render to render / instead of /participants because this is only possible through post?

Comment: render is used after the request has been already done so you can't change the url without redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

See the line `root        /                                participants#new` when you do `rake routes`. So your route is taking you to the `participants#new`.

As in `routes.rb`, when you use `root :to => 'participants#new'` and then `redirect_to root_path`, it will go to the `participants#new` and wherever you use `/`, it is equivalent to `root_url`.

For example:

When you write the following url locally:

```
http://my_host_name/
```

It is actually going to -

```
http://my_host_name/participants/new
```

So as in your create action you have this line:

```
format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "...."}
```

It is redirecting to -

```
http://my_host_name/participants/new
```

Comment: So there's no solution to this? I can't get the render to render / instead of /participants?

Comment: In this scenario the answer is no because `render /` is nothing but `render root_url`. So whatever you put in `root :to` of `routes.rb`, that will be your rendered path. Here it is `/participants` so you are getting that only rendered.

Comment: this is incorrect. render is only used to show what template, file or what response you want to send the browser. it has nothing to do with the url.

Comment: @jvnill Ah I knew that what you said but didn't thought like that. That's right. Sorry for the confusion. Actually, I mean to say it in context of routes.rb that when you use `root :to => 'participants#new'` and then `redirect_to root_path`, it will go to the `participants#new` and wherever you use `/`, it is equivalent to `root_url`.